# How to access an id of an html element with c#

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0, getelementbyid

I have the following code:
HTML

```
<label id="myLabel"></label>
<button id="myButton">My Button</button>
```

CSHARP

```
public void myButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I want to set the label text to say Hi when the button is clicked, I have been having a very tough time doing this simple task even though I understand the c# language. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The html is on the browser, while C# runs on the server. So it is not simple.

Comment: Is this webforms? You then need to add "runat=server" to those elements, so you can access them server-side (on postback)

Comment: Is this asp.net core blazor? If yes, then check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @HansKeﬆing This is an ASP.Net Core Web Application, I have Tried adding runat=server and it hasn't worked.

Comment: @Pethical This is an ASP.Net Core Web Application

Comment: Can you use JavaScript? Or you must use C#?

Comment: @Alex-TinLe I could use javascript for some of it although I just learned c# so I am not looking to base an entire project around a language I don't know.

Comment: Well, to quickly explain, C# is not used for this purpose. C# is for server side code which is for web server to handle http requests. Changing a label when clicking button isn't a http request, but an Html DOM updating operation. And JS is suitable for it.

Comment: @Alex-TinLe I'm confused becuase the main purpose I learned c# was so that I could make ios app. I don't have a mac so I am using Visual Studio to create it although I don't get why c# can be used for the backend of an ios app but not web app

Comment: If you want to compile for iOS, you still need a Mac somewhere - rules of Apple

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I know I have a virtual mac, the only reason I don't code on there is because it's slow.

Comment: I don't know iOS development, so I have a hard time combining app development with the need to access specific html elements. So maybe you need to explain a bit more about how your app combines those? Is it a (web-)server that communicates with a browser, or some sort of WebControl inside your app that gets its html from within the app?